# How to work around TiCDC atomic transactional limitations?

Tags: tidb

I'm learning about TiCDC. As I read the documentation, it seems that TiCDC basically replicates changes in each key-value pair rather than the unit of transaction (which may include multiple key-value pairs). This means that if I were to use TiCDC for DR, replicating the data to a different region, I might see partially committed data in that? Thus, I was interested, when we do DR failover, how can we ensure that we have failovered to a transactionally consistent point in time (all changes are atomic)?